# What is Best Practice of CMS in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, content-management-system

I have MVC Project that contain many views,
I want the client to edit the content as he/she like and save it.

How I can make CMS (content management system )of the views?

I have read about RedEditor in telerik but it work only with html files ,
 the MVC is cshtml files that contain razor and I can't deal with by RedEditor.

My problem that I have a built website for client, and now the client request to modify the website as he like , Modify content ..Images ..etc, and all views built by razor

Ex : this is page maked by razor
I want the admin client modify the titles & picture & after save reflect it in the live website

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do a simple content management system in MVC, you probably want to organize things so that the page model is a list of content items, so that your view iterates the content items and displays them

```
public partial class Content
{
    public Content()
    {
        this.Pages = new HashSet<Page>();
    }

    public int ContentID { get; set; }
    public string ContentTitle { get; set; }
    public string ContentImage { get; set; }
    public string ContentImageAlt { get; set; }
    public string ContentTitleLink { get; set; }
    public string ContentImageLink { get; set; }
    public string ContentBody { get; set; }
    public string ContentTeaser { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ContentDate { get; set; }
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
    public int SortKey { get; set; }
    public int ContentTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentType ContentType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

The the view is simply

```
        @foreach (var art in Model.Content)
        {
            <text>
                @Html.DynamicPageContent(art)
            </text>
        }
```

and the helper that uses is

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DynamicPageContent(this HtmlHelper helper, Content content)
    {
        if (content.ContentType==null) return new MvcHtmlString(content.ContentBody);
        return content == null ? null : MvcHtmlString.Create(  String.Format("\n<!--{0}: {1}({2})-->\n",content.ContentID, content.ContentType.ContentTypeDescription, content.ContentTypeID)+helper.Partial(content.ContentType.TemplateName, content).ToString().Trim());
    }
```

where each Content.ContentType contains a TemplateName which is an MVC view name.

So the main view then renders a number of parital views. The simmplest of my partial views just contains @Html.Raw(content.Body), others render more strcutured content using the properties of the Content class: I've got one for managed images, one for News Articles etc.

Then in your back end you can use the Kendo controls (or other) to edit the ContentBody, ContentTeaser etc, just setting an appropriate ContentType which names the partial view to render it.

Hopefully that will give you enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you :)
my problem that I have a built website for client, and now the client request to modify the website as he like , Modify content ..Images ..etc, and all views built by razor

Comment: The only way you could do that directly would be to have some code that read the razor views server side, and allowed those to be edited - after all they are only files and are compiled at run time. However, going from a non-content managed site to a content managed one is probably best done by introducing a CMS. As a suggestion, Umbraco is Razor based, allows server side editing of templates and is pretty nice for editors to use. However, its File: New-Project time!